# Get CMake to execute a target in project before building a library

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I am using CMake to build my C++ project and it has multiple executables and a library (all part of same project).  All is working fine, however one of my executables is a code generator that creates some of the library classes. I have got all the generation working but can't figure out how to call this executable (codegen) just before the library is built. I am on Linux environment.  Hope someone can answer this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In `CMakeLists.txt`:

First, define your executable:

```
add_executable(marks-code-generator gen.cpp)
```

Then, define a custom command to generate the source:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT generated.cpp generated.hpp
                   COMMAND marks-code-generator ARGS args here maybe
                   MAIN_DEPENDENCY input-file.in
                   DEPENDS marks-code-generator
                   COMMENT here we go!
                   VERBATIM)
```

The option `VERBATIM` makes sure platform-specific escaping is done correctly. The `COMMENT` will be printed out as make executes, giving something like `[ 66%] here we go!`.

Finally, name your generated source in the source list for your real program:

```
add_executable(some-program generated.cpp generated.hpp non-generated.cpp foo.cpp)
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, 
Should marks-code-generator write the generated.cpp/h files to current dir or simple output them to stdout and let the OUTPUT part write them? If so do I just separate them with an EOF when writing?

Comment: I'm increasingly of the opinion that recursive build systems don't work. They don't work with `make`, they don't work with `automake` and I don't believe they work with `CMake`. Is there any reason you can't do this all in a toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`? Use `include` if it gets too big.

You still need to output to a file. The `OUTPUT` line in `add_custom_command` just tells CMake what files you're generating (since there's no way it could work that out on its own), so keep using an `ofstream` or whatever to generate your header and source.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I will look at moving to one CMakeLists, seems like it would be easier to maintain etc.

Comment: It's true that those other system require you to put everything into one giant file, but recursive CMake works fine.  It will manage the dependencies (yes really).

Comment: @JackKelly: How would you handle the situation where the code generators outputs a variable number of files?