# Using two tool-chains with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

For cross-compiling projects for a microcontroller (msp430 from TI), I use the clang++ and the mspgcc from TI.
Basically the compile process is as follows:

```
file.cpp 
--(llvm clang++)--> file.ll 
--(llvm llc)--> file.s 
--(ti msp430-elf-gcc)--> file.o 
--(ti msp430-elf-gcc)--> a.out (executable)
```

What I want to do, is compile my projects with cmake. I have read about the toolchain option for cmake (e.g. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html?highlight=toolchain), but it does not quite fit my situation.

Any possibilities to achieve it?

---

The exact steps for compiling are:

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -I ~/ti/gcc/include/ -I ~/ti/gcc/msp430-elf/include/ -D__MSP430F5529__ -S -emit-llvm -std=c++11 --target=msp430 -Wall -c file.cpp -o file.ll

/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/llc -march=msp430 file.ll -o file.s

~/ti/gcc/bin/msp430-elf-gcc -Wall -D_GNU_ASSEMBLER_ -I ~/ti/gcc/include/ -mmcu=msp430f5529 -mcpu=430 -x assembler -Wa,-gstabs -c file.s -o file.o

~/ti/gcc/bin/msp430-elf-gcc -mmcu=msp430f5529 -B ~/ti/gcc/include/ -mcpu=430 -Wl,-Map=a.out.map file.o  -o a.out
```

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a longer toolchain (more steps, but still essentially sequential as opposed to parallel / orthogonal), rather than multiple toolchains.

Comment: As @ChintalagiriShashank said, you just need to specify different tools for different steps: `clang++` as C++ compiler, `llc` as .ll compiler (whatever this means), `msp430-elf-gcc` as ASM compiler and as linker.

Comment: Yes, I take tools from different toolchains to form a new longer toolchain. I know how to set the C++-compiler, the ASM-compiler and the linker. But how do I tell cmake to add the extra step from the .ll (llvm intermediate assembler) to .s (target assembler) file?

Comment: `But how do I tell cmake to add the extra step...` - as far as I know, you cannot: CMake distinguish only *compile* and *link* stages. So you need to combine step manually. Or somehow to automates this process with defining function/macro or creating special compile script, which produces object file from C one.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, though admittedly suboptimal, you could treat one of the compile commands as simply a [custom command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html).

Note that this approach will give you little more than a regular old shell script with a lot of added on syntactical headaches for the step you use it for.

From the commands you've listed, it looks like you're only using `msp430-elf-gcc` for converting an otherwise fully integrated assembly listing into msp430 hex. If that is the case, I'd set up the toolchain to handle `clang++` and all the dependency resolution that goes with compiling serious programs. The later `msp430-elf-gcc` command can simply be listed as a custom command which includes the target of your `clang++` build as a dependency. In fact, all of the last three steps you have are fairly straightforward in that regard and may well be amenable to being essentially hardcoded.See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5385413/1934174).

A slightly cleaner approach, though you might have to put in some effort to make sure it's sufficient or not, would be to link the custom_command to the target. Meta-code from a cursory reading of the `add_custom_command` docs :

```
add_executable(file.ll ${SOURCES})
add_custom_command(TARGET file.ll
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND llc [ARGS] [args1...]
                   COMMAND msp430-elf-gcc [ARGS] [args2...] 
                   COMMAND msp430-elf-gcc [ARGS] [args3...] 
                   [WORKING_DIRECTORY dir]
                   [COMMENT comment] [VERBATIM])
```

My initial impression is that `add_custom_command` with the `OUTPUT` based signature (as opposed to the `TARGET` based signature) may prove to be more intuitive, but that would depend on your personal preferences as well as the overall complexity of your build.

Ideally, you'd have to set up a more complicated build using either [ExternalProject](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html) or running cmake twice with different CMakeLists. I've never had to do either badly enough to figure out how that works, though.